# PHP variable doesn't iterate

Tags: php, variables, slider

For my image slider, I need to add a slider id to all buttons in it. I created variable $currSlider and iterate it before use. But in all 4 buttons, it's got the same result.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { //this cycle does 2 iterations
    $currSlider=0;//here it's zero
    $photoQuery = "SELECT * FROM tphoto WHERE coinId=".$row['id'];
    $photos = mysqli_query($sql, $photoQuery);
    echo('<div class="country_data">
          Country: '.$row['country_name'].'<br>
          Value: '.$row['nominal_name'].' '.$row['curency_name'].'<br>
          Metal: '.$row['metal_name'].'<br>
          Creation: '.$row['dateCreation'].'<br>
          Weight: '.$row['weight'].'<br>
          Mintage: '.$row['mintage'].'<br><br>
          </div>');
    if (mysqli_num_rows($photos) > 0) {
        echo('<div class="coin_img_div">');
        while($photoRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($photos)) {
            echo('<img class="slide" src="/../img/collection/'.$photoRow['photoPath'].'">');
        }
        echo('<a class="sliderPrev" onclick="plusDivs(-1, '.++$currSlider.');">&#10094;</a>//there it's one always.
        <a class="sliderNext" onclick="plusDivs(1, '.$currSlider.');">&#10095</a>//and there too.
        </div>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialise `$currSlider` outside of the while loop.

If you initialise the variable inside the while loop, you are setting it to zero each time round your loop.

So

```
$currSlider = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { //this cycle does 2 iterations

// dont do it in here
// $currSlider=0;//here it's zero
```

Answer (score 0):

Your next and previous buttons have the same value.

You have added the post increment operator to your next button id (++), which increases the id by 1.

You need to add the post increment operator (++) to your previous button as well. So your code should look like:

```
echo('<a class="sliderPrev" onclick="plusDivs(-1, '.++$currSlider.');">&#10094;</a>//there it's one always.

<a class="sliderNext" onclick="plusDivs(1, '.++$currSlider.');">&#10095</a>//and there too.
```

Comment: They must have same values. It's id of a slider